# Move non-movable apps to SD Card on rooted phone

Tags: applications, internal-storage, external-sd, sd-card, app2sd

I have some big apps like Spotify on my phone which has not much empty space left on my internal storage. So I considered moving not only movable apps to sd card but others as well. I know that Spotify for example comes with a widget that will be broken but I don't care. How can I move those apps to the SD Card? My phone (LG Optimus L9 II) is rooted and I don't mind creating some symlinks or something like that via adb.

After using google I also tried this command:

```
pm set-install-location 2
```

as root, but Spotify is still in my internal storage.

Answer (score 1):

If your phone has a setting like Settings>Storage>Default Storage Location then set it to SD Card instead of Internal Storage. Alternatively there are Apps that can offer a solution.

The App Link2SD allows you to move apps to a second partition on your SD card. You'll need to create that partition first.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD

A different approach is used by Directory Bind at xda-developers. You don't need to change your SD card in any way as you have to do with Link2SD.

http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s2/themes-apps/tool-directorybind-data-to-externalsd-t1410262

I've used both and they both did the job.

Comment: The command I executed does pretty much change the default storage location, but I think this only applies to apps installed after that change or?